# Increase number in a string by one

Tags: applescript

Very new to Applescript and looking for some help. I already have a script that will increase the number at the end of this filename, RM5_CA_0_4C_288.tif, by one and it works great. But sometimes I need that string to increase by 1 but it has letters before or after the last set of numbers (i.e. _A288.tif or _288A.tif). How do I increase the number by 1 with letters before or after it?

My script copies a filename to the clipboard, increases it by one, and pastes the result back to the clipboard.

Thanks for the help!

Original script to increase by one:

```
try

set oldName to the clipboard

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}

set oldNumber to the last text item of oldName

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"."}

set oldNumber to the first text item of oldNumber

set newNumber to oldNumber + 1

set newNumber to newNumber & "tif" as string

set xVar to 1
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}
set newName to ""
repeat while xVar is less than 5
    set newName to newName & text item xVar of oldName & "_"

    set xVar to xVar + 1
end repeat

set newName to newName & newNumber

set the clipboard to newName as string
on error tell application "Firefox" to display dialog "Error! Check the 'set AppleScript's text item delimiters to' section. Change the delimeter?" buttons ["OK"] default button 1 
return 
end try
```

---

In progress script to include the letters before / after numbers:

```
set oldName to the clipboard

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}

set oldNumber to the last text item of oldName

get result

set returnedString to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of result & " | tr -d '[:upper:]'"

get result

set returnedString to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of result & " | tr -dc '[:digit:]'"

set result to result as number

set newNumber to result + 1

set newNumber to newNumber & ".tif" as string

get result

set theName to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of result & " | tr -d '\"_'"
```

Comment: Show your code so far. And specify if you're wanting file "_289A.tif" to go to "_290A.tif", or even "_299A.tif" to go to "_300A.tif", and is there a "_999A.tif" that will need to add another digit?

Comment: Is there always an underscore `_` before the last digits you want to increment by 1? Also, show use the _code_ you're currently using.

Comment: Yes. There is always an _ before the last set of numbers but sometimes there is a letter before or after the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @jweaks! So helpful! 

If I run this script using ""UM5_CA_0_4C_A1.tif"" I get what the result I want, "UM5_CA_0_4C_A2.tif". Similarly, if the oldName is "UM5_CA_0_4C_1A.tif" I also get the result I would expect. BUT if the oldName was "UM5_CA_0_4C_A1A.tif", I get a result that doesn't work.  Thoughts?

Comment: That's because I structured it according to your request. You said "it has letters before or after the last set of numbers". You didn't say it could have it both. You need to unnest the Try blocks in this instance. (and, you should comment on the answer, not the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. Using text item delimiters is a fine way of grabbing the last string part, but since I'm suggesting using do shell script to call regular expressions to match string portions, might as well do so for each part.

```
set oldName to "RM5_CA_0_4C_288.tif"

-- get everything up through the last _
set firstPart to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of oldName & " | grep -o '\\w*_'"
-- get everything from the last _
set lastPart to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of oldName & " | grep -o '_[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*\\.tif'"
-- get the simplified string in the lastPart
set lastPart to text 2 thru -5 of lastPart

try -- check for leading letters
    set preLetters to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of lastPart & " | grep -o '^[a-zA-Z]'"
    set theNumber to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of lastPart & " | grep -o '[0-9]*$'"
    set postLetters to ""
on error
    try -- check for trailing letters
        set postLetters to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of lastPart & " | grep -o '[a-zA-Z]$'"
        set theNumber to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of lastPart & " | grep -o '^[0-9]*'"
        set preLetters to ""
    on error -- has no letters
        set theNumber to lastPart
        set preLetters to ""
        set postLetters to ""
    end try
end try

-- increment the number string
set newNumber to theNumber + 1
-- put humpty dumpty back together again
set newName to firstPart & preLetters & newNumber & postLetters & ".tif"
```

Comment: I have since update part of this script. I ran into filenames that included decimal points (2229_CA_0_79.1_111.tif). When I ran the script as written above, it deleted parts of the filename I needed to stay intact (2229_CA_0_79.1_111.tif > 2229_CA_0_1_112.tif).  To fix this I changed the grep command. I also have the original filename copying to the clipboard.    
                                                              set oldName to the clipboard
set firstPart to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of oldName & " | grep -o '\\w.*_'"

Answer (score -1):

Original script to increase by one:

```
try

    set oldName to the clipboard

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}

    set oldNumber to the last text item of oldName

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"."}

    set oldNumber to the first text item of oldNumber

    set newNumber to oldNumber + 1

    set newNumber to newNumber & "tif" as string

    set xVar to 1
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}
    set newName to ""
    repeat while xVar is less than 5
        set newName to newName & text item xVar of oldName & "_"

        set xVar to xVar + 1
    end repeat

    set newName to newName & newNumber

    set the clipboard to newName as string

on error
    tell application "Firefox" to display dialog "Error! Check the 'set AppleScript's text item delimiters to' section.  Change the delimeter?" buttons ["OK"] default button 1
    return
end try
```